# flutter firebase how do I get all the children of a node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am not very familiar with using dart and firebase and I was wondering how I could get all the children of a certain node and how I could check if a node exists

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code and errors within your question as text. Linking to images hurts our ability to answer your question, and using images for code or error messages makes searching for similar errors impossible. If you have questions please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you I will make sure I'll keep that in mind the next time I ask a question @StefanCrain

Comment: You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49799171/edit) button to make a change after you've posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should you get the list of users:

```
static Future<int> getUserAmount() async {
  final response = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child("Users")
      .once();
  var users = [];
  reponse.value.forEach((v) => users.add(v));
  print(users);
  return users.length;
}
```

You can check with `users` what you need to check and then return a result;

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the name of the parentes of the example bellow:

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjxbJ.png**

I'd use the code of **Günter Zöchbauer** with a little modification. The result will be: **user = [A,B,C,D,E,LIVRE]**  with 5 length size.

```
Future  getUserAmount() async
  {
    final database = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child("CHILD1/ana/exercicios/")
      .once();
      
    List <String> users = [];

    database.value.forEach((key,values) => users.add(key)); 

    print(users);
    print(users.length);
  }
```