# Flutter Retrieve Data From Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, dart, buffer

[image]

I want to get list of child from this hierarchy chats>inbox>id>child from firebase realtime database,
I tried this to read the data.. I got child with child's data.. but how can I retrieve list of child without child's data while child doesnt have any key to be called?

```
await FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child("inbox")
      .child(userId)
      .once()
      .then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
        Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value).forEach((key,values) {
          setState(() {
            print(snapshot.value);
          });
        });
    });
```

the snapshot.value returns: i want to get the red lines data
[image]

Comment: `print(snapshot.value);` does this work? If so, what does it print? Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799171/flutter-firebase-how-do-i-get-all-the-children-of-a-node)?

Comment: it returns child with child's data.. but i dont know how to return just the child(28,34,35 ..)

Comment: You want to get the key? `print(snapshot.key)`

Comment: please check the updated question, i want to get the red line data

Comment: my bad, sorry, it works, why do i put snapshot.value not values lol. thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

just remove `print(snapshot.value)` with `print(key)`

Comment: Asker took time to drill down and provide a detailled question. Please do the same if you're trying to answer. Any piece of advice, reason or reference. You're giving a solution here, not a proper answer.

Comment: The asker took my answer from the comments and posted it himself here to his own question.